# django user specific authentication method

Tags: django, multi-tenant, django-authentication

I am planning a django web application with multiple tenants (or i call it companies).

This means that my web application is used by multiple companies. Every company could shall set their own authentication method. For example company 1 and company 2 would like to use active directory and company 3 and 4 use the default django authentication system.
But the users can associated with more than one company.

I have build a little diagram:
[image]

And at this point i'm stuck.

Only existing users with the specific permission can create new user accounts. The primary key of a user is the email adress.

I think the companies should "register" their domain if they would like to use another authentication method.
For example company 1 have the domain xyz.de and all users in my web app with the domain in their email adress must authenticate them over the active directory from company 1.

I think the user could type only their email adress in the login form and django can check if a specific authentication method is configured for the domain. And in the next step the user can type the password or he is redirect to the other authentication system.

I have following questions:

1. How can i implement that?
2. Is there a better way to implement my requirements?
3. Exist already a package that can help me?
4. What happens if a user is already authenticate by another authentication system and come to my web app? Can i check if the user already authenticate or must the user login via the login page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in similar project, our solution for this structure is:

**1. Create `UserParent` table in public schema**

- include some infor of account parent

**2. Create `UserParentRelation` table in public schema**

- parent_user_id (fk to `UserParent`)
- tenant_id (fk to `Tenant/Company`)

**3. Depend on your account management in Tenant site**

- In my case, when create new record in `UserParentRelation`, an account in `Tenant/Company` was created
- Then you should handle Middleware when redirect to another `Tenant/Company`